# laravel 5 , how to handle created_at automatically but not the updated_at

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

as said in laravel's documents, eloquent can take care of created_at and updated_at fields, what if I want laravel to only take care of created_at, and leave the updated_at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eloquent handles the timestamps in `updateTimestamps()`:

```
protected function updateTimestamps()
{
    $time = $this->freshTimestamp();

    if ( ! $this->isDirty(static::UPDATED_AT))
    {
        $this->setUpdatedAt($time);
    }

    if ( ! $this->exists && ! $this->isDirty(static::CREATED_AT))
    {
        $this->setCreatedAt($time);
    }
}
```

You can simply override this function in your model and remove the `updatedAt` part:

```
protected function updateTimestamps()
{
    $time = $this->freshTimestamp();

    if ( ! $this->exists && ! $this->isDirty(static::CREATED_AT))
    {
        $this->setCreatedAt($time);
    }
}
```

---

Or you could just override `setUpdatedAt`, although you would might want to keep that to intentionally set the value:

```
public function setUpdatedAt($value)
{
    // do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve the one above, is to alter to model events. Add the following method to your model.

```
public static function boot()
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function($model) {
        $dateTime = new DateTime;
        $model->created_at = $dateTime->format('m-d-y H:i:s');
        return true;
    });

    static::updating(function($model) {
        $dateTime = new DateTime;
        $model->updated_at = $dateTime->format('m-d-y H:i:s');
        return true;
    });
}
```

Now you can access the creating and updating model events. Within these events you can do what ever you want, in your case you can alter timestamps. For more information on model events please refer to the Laravel documentation [Model Events](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events)

Answer (score 0):

Its all or nothing for out of the box functionality.

Replicating the functionality for just the `created_at` you could use the eloquent events. For each of your models you could do the following

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent
{

    protected $timestamps = false;

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function($model)
        {
            $model->created_at = Carbon::now();
        });
    }

}
```

Every time a new model is created, this will set the `created_at` column to the current time using Carbon.